# Finding permutation and combination in C++

Tags: c++

I want to find a series of numbers of dynamic length in C++. Suppose I have 2 groups of numbers: `arr1[3] = {1, 3, 8}` and `arr2[4] = {2, 9}`, then the expected output is:

```
'1, 2',
'1, 9',
'3, 2',
'3, 9',
'8, 2',
'8, 9'.
```

However, if there are 3 groups now : `arr1[3] = {1, 3, 8}`, `arr2[2] = {2, 9}` and `arr3[5] = {1, 3, 9}` then the output should be:

```
'1, 2, 1',
'1, 2, 3',
'1, 2, 9',
'1, 9, 1',
'1, 9, 3',
'1, 9, 9',
'3, 2, 1',
'3, 2, 3',
'3, 2, 9',
'3, 9, 1',
'3, 9, 3',
'3, 9, 9',
```

and so on...

So there will 3 x 2 x 3 = 18 outcomes. I got the outcome for 2 groups and 3 groups using respective numbers of for loops.

See this code for 2 groups:

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) { 
   for (int j=1;j<=5;j++) { 
       cout << i << "," << j << "," << endl; 
   } 
}
```

But then I have to use different codes for different value of group number and have to use switch statement or if-else statement to choose that portion of code.

This will be a great help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create an array of pointers or indexes into each sequence; they start by pointing to the first element of their corresponding sequence. Then repeatedly do this: increment the last index; if it reaches the end of its sequence, reset it to zero and increment next-to-last one; if *that* one reaches the end, reset it to zero and increment the previous one, and so on. Stop when the first index reaches the end. This way, you will systematically enumerate all combinations.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, yeah, textbook solution, as I was coding :-).

Comment: For permutation C++ standard library (std) provides `next_permutation` function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/ and for combination you can just ignore the repetitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used vector instead of arrays, as they are way easier to deal with.

The trick is to enumerate, in lexicographic order, the positions in the arrays, then display the values at those positions:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;

void permutate(vector<vector<int>> values)
{
    // the positions in each vector
    vector<size_t> pos(values.size());

    do
    {
        // display one of each array at current position
        for(size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << values[i][pos[i]] << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        // increment the last array's display position
        size_t p = 0;
        pos[p]++;

        // while we get to the end of current array, return to 0 and carry to next position
        while(pos[p] == values[p].size())
        {
            pos[p] = 0;
            p++;
            pos[p]++;

            // return when the last array's position get to its size
            if (p == values.size())
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    while(true);

}

int main()
{
    vector<int> arr1 = {1, 3, 8};
    vector<int> arr2 = {2, 9};
    vector<int> arr3 = {1, 3, 9};

    vector<vector<int>> allThree = {arr1, arr2, arr3};

    permutate(allThree);
}
```

A good exercise, next, would be to template it so you accept `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`

Comment: Woah, good point. I took care to compile with `-Wall --pedantic`.  Seems like I missed `-Wconversion`